# How to stop touch event when certain position is reached?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement functions with touch events on a list of items. The problem is I don't know how to stop `touchmove` when the end (or the start) of my list  is reached. I don't know to to stop scroll right when I'm at the end but still allow to scroll left.

I was thinking about adding `pointer-events: none` when I'm at the end of the list but of course after this I can't scroll left.

Maybe I should create different functions for scrolling left or right? Or there is some other way to do this.

All help would be much appreciated.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => handleTouchStart(e), false);
container.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => handleTouchMove(e), false);
let xDiff = null
let pos = 0;

function handleTouchMove(evt) {

  if (!this.xDown) {
    return;
  }

  let xUp = evt.touches[0].clientX;
  let xDiff = xDown - xUp;


  if (Math.abs(xDiff)) {
    if (xDiff < 0) {
      prev();
    } else {
      next();
    }
  }

  /* reset values */
  xDown = null;
}

function handleTouchStart(evt) {
  xDown = evt.touches[0].clientX;
};

function next() {
  pos += 10
  container.style.marginLeft = pos + 'px'
}
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/1kz888dd/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*Kindly use touchmove event and the value will be false see below the examples**


$('.list .items').bind('touchmove', false);
```

Comment: I think bind in JQuery is deprecated. And I don't want to use somehting other than vanilla javascript if it is possible